# React Native - Update and Delete by ID

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'am trying to **Update** and **Delete** some items by **ID** upon tap/click of Update And Remove buttons. But my problems is, I'm not sure what is the proper approach doing a "fetch with a **state**(or anything) for the ID's".

- With these approach, I have errors. (Ex: undefined is not an object ...)
- Without these, I have nothing. I'am well aware of that because I'm not referring to anything. So I have to use **ID**. But I don't know the approach.

Please help, anything will be appreciated. :)

Here is my code

Settlement.js

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            ...
            deleteOrder: '',
            numOrder: '',
        };
    }

    submit = () => {
        this.state.numOrder = item.order_id;     // here's my fetch with state
        fetch('http://192.168.254.***:****/SendOrder/update' + this.state.numOrder, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                spcl_req: this.state.SplOrder,
                order_quantity: this.state.count,
                order_type: this.state.DineIn,
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
                console.log(responseJson);
            })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    }
    delete = () => {
        this.state.deleteOrder = item.order_id;     // here's my fetch with state
        fetch('http://192.168.254.***:****/SendOrder/delete_order/' + this.state.deleteOrder, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                order_id: this.state.deleteOrder
            })
        }).then((responseData) => {
            Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseData))
            console.log(responseData.rows)
        }).done();
    }

    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                ...
                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                    <View>
                        ....
                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress = { () => this.submit() }>
                                <Text>UPDATE</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress = { () => this.delete() }>
                                <Text>REMOVE</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You broke a couple of concepts in React.

this.state.numOrder = item.order_id;
This line will not update your state

What's in the item in this line? renderItem = {({ item }) =>

Perhaps in this object there is an identifier, which must be passed as an argument to your functions

Comment: the "item" from ''this.state.numOrder' is from my api. and for the "renderItem = {({ item }) =>" I use it to declare some data from my api, i just didn't show it here because others might get confuse on it and the code will get long.

Comment: try to pass as an argument to the function
It should look something like this:

onPress = { () => this.submit(item.order_id) }>

in your function:
submit = id => {
  fetch(`url/${id}` ...etc
}

Comment: Should I keep "this.state.numOrder = item.order_id;" and "+ this.state.numOrder" in my fetch then?

Comment: In this example, you can do without a store

Comment: And update state need another way, see the documentation